# What's the fastest way to add / subtract a value from an array of numbers?

Tags: go

I have the code below, would like to add / subtract the value "1" from each element. What's the fastest way to do this? Asked because I have 1 million elements within myByte array. The below code only shows 3, but if there's a million, it'll take a very very long time.

```
myByte := []byte("a","b","c")

for i:=0; i<len(myByte); i++ {
    myByte[i]+=1
}
```

Comment: There is no single "fastest" way. Write an appropriate benchmark using the tooling provided by go test -bench and package testing and experiment on all the relevant hardware. Note that working sequentially through memory is pretty fast as hardware is optimized for this type of workload. Depending on _your_ exact hardware setup working on the first and second half in parallel might be worth a try. Don't expect that dividing into lots of chunks will decrease wall time spent a lot as you just will trash your processor cache.

Comment: One more: a million bytes is basically _nothing_ on modern hardware. If this is not on your hot code path: Do not bother yourself with microoptimisations which take a lot of time to implement, to debug, to maintain but do not provide real measurable improvements to you program.

Comment: What @Volker says is correct.  Probably one good way to spend your time is looking at allocation memory optimisations.  This article is of interest https://segment.com/blog/allocation-efficiency-in-high-performance-go-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time it and try parallelising

```
package add

import (
        "testing"
)


func BenchmarkSimple(b *testing.B) {
        // to run use go test -bench=.
        var array=make([]byte,1000000)
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
               addit(&array,1)
        }
}

func BenchmarkPara(b *testing.B) {
        // to run use go test -bench=.
        var array=make([]byte,1000000)
        var p1=array[0:250000]
        var p2=array[250001:500000]
        var p3=array[500001:750000]
        var p4=array[750001:999999]
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
               go addit(&p1,1)
               go addit(&p2,1)
               go addit(&p3,1)
               go addit(&p4,1)
        }
}


func addit(myByte *[]byte, v byte) {
for i:=0; i<len(*myByte); i++ {
    (*myByte)[i]+=v
}
}
```

Here's what I see on my laptop. My laptop has 4 cores

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkSimple-4           1130           1035976 ns/op
BenchmarkPara-4            10000            559050 ns/op
PASS
ok      _/Users/jamandre/wip/add        6.923s
```

Timing isn't as clever as it seems for stuff like this, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TLSBdHe1A&t=46s But do time it!

Four go routines doesn't give 4x speed up, about 2 x is pretty good

Comment: Try passing the slices by value, no need for the pointer indirection.

Comment: Yes, you are right passing in that way seems faster / less cpu / better / simpler

Answer (score 2):

Divide and conquer. Split your huge array into N contiguous sections and then handle each section with a goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelizing your code may help, parallel processing is a first class citizen in Go, hence the [`go` instruction and *goroutines*](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency).

Also [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions allow for vast performance improvements for such computations. [Here is a Go package to use them](https://godoc.org/github.com/slimsag/rand/simd).